# PHP version change for single domain | browser download it

Tags: php, apache, version

My Webhoster doesnt accept PHP Version change for single domains. The PHP version (7.3) work only for all domains on my webhost account. But for one domain, i need 5.3 and i cant configure it.
I can made extensions in "Apache-Configuration" > "for single Domains" but i dont know what command code i need here. I tried second way, in htaccess to force it via "AddHandler..." "AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php" but the browser open/download a file instead.

can it be that my webhost does not allow simultaneous use of different versions? is there any possibility ?

Try all solution on stackoverflow i found. (My Site is a index.php)
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-3 .php

No PHP changing. Instead, browser want downloading a file.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use, for php 7.3:

```
#AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml .html .htm
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

You may want to consider switching your webhost... the standard version of cPanel allows for multiple PHP installations, configurable per domain.

Comment: Hi FoulFoot. I tried, but doesnt work :(
I wrote to my Hoster, but they said that the normal webhost service havnt a multiple PHP using or installation. I can only activate the PHP version for the complete Hosting, all Domains in there :(
I hoped, that any commands in the Apache Configuration can handle it. Or maybe a htaccess change.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can configure per-domain using htaccess.  I suggest you get a new web host.  I could recommend mine, but that probably violates a StackOverflow rule.